my flask app is locally working but not able to deploy globally


from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from meta_ai_api import MetaAI
from flask_cors import CORS
import logging
from main import MetaAI
import sys
import os

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
src_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, src_dir)


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})


ai = MetaAI()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


# Serve the HTML file
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

# API endpoint
@app.route('/endpoint', methods=['POST'])
def handle_chatbot_request():
    message = request.json['message']
    response = ai.prompt(message)
    return jsonify({'response': response})


if __name__ == '__main__':
 #    app.run(debug=True)

#if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)  


I have the Flask app with implementing Meta.AI. It is running successfully in my local. I am getting the proper response from the Chatbot. But when I deploy in Global Like Render, Vercel, Heroku, I do not get a reaction from chatbot. I am always getting internal server errors.
Here is my code App.py:

I work at Render.
Glancing at your code there are a few reasons why you could get a 500 error, so you'll need to check your service's logs from your Render dashboard. Select your service and choose "Logs" from the left side menu.
Some things that come to mind that you don't describe in your question:

Are you using a requirements.txt and building a virtual environment as part of your deployment so Render has access to things like MetaAI?
You're importing two things called MetaAI which could cause a conflict.
Your home() method is calling render_template() -- is that set up correctly? you're only showing us one file of your whole Flask app
You have a __main__ check around app.run so I assume you're using something like gunicorn or uvicorn to run your code? is that launching correctly?

